LTL Model Checking Worst Case size for NBA
I have a slide that gives the worst case time complexity of LTL model checking which uses a product construction of an LTS along with the NBA for the negation of the LTL formula.

My question is, when does this worst case complexity happen, for what LTL formula (its negation) does the corresponding size of the NBA become exponential in the number of operators.

I don't understand what you are asking or what kind answer you are looking for.  I don't know what it means to ask "when does this happen" or how one is supposed to answer that.

@D.W. I've edited it, essentially for what LTL formula do we get an NBA that has size exponential in the number of operators

Usually there are infinitely many problem instances that cause an algorithm to hit its worst-case running time.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting or hoping for.

@D.W. Just wondering if there are any easy-to-see/interesting examples where this happens

For a lower-bound, for $n\geq 1$, consider the following language over $\{0, 1, \#, \text{$\\\$$}\}$: $$ L_n = \{ \{ 0, 1, \#\}^* \cdot \#\cdot w\cdot \# \cdot \{ 0, 1, \#\}^* \cdot $ \cdot w\cdot \#^\omega: w\in \{ 0, 1\}^n \}$$
Thus, an infinite word $x$ is in $L_n$ only when its infix of length $n$ that comes after the single $\\\$$  appears
somewhere before the $\\\$$.
Is is known that a minimal deterministic automaton for $L_n$ requires $2^{2^n}$ states. Intuitively, upon reaching the $\\\$$, the automaton should've remembered the set of binary words of length $n$ that appeared in the past. Since you are interested in going to a nondeterministic automaton, then the bound size reduces to $2^n$ as you can guess which word $w$ is going to appear after the $\#$, and then check if that guess is correct. It is now a simple standard exercise to show that we need guesses corresponding to every binary word $w$ of length $n$, and thus at least $2^n$ states.
We can specify $L_n$ by an LTL formula $\Psi = \Psi_1 \wedge \Psi_2$, where:

$\Psi_1$  makes sure that there is a single $\\\$$ followed by a word of the form $(0+1)^n \#^\omega$, and

$\Psi_2$ makes sure that eventually there exists a position with $\#$ and for all $i\in [n]$, the $i$-th letter from this position is in $\{0, 1\}$ and it agrees with the $i$-th letter after the $\\\$$ (note that this requires the binary word of length $n$ after the $\#$ to be identical to that after the $\\\$$). Also, the $(n+1)$-th letter from this position is $\#$ (this requires that the binary word after the $\#$ is of length exactly $n$).


We can define:
$\Psi_1 =  (\neg\text{$\\\$$})U(\text{$\\\$$}\wedge X((0\lor 1)∧X((0\lor1) \stackrel{n}{\cdots}  X((0\lor1)\wedge XG\#)))\cdots)$
$\Psi_2 = F(\#\wedge X^{n+1}\#\wedge \bigwedge\limits_{1\leq i \leq n}
((X^i0\wedge G(\text{$\\\$$} \to X^i 0))\lor(X^i 1\wedge G(\text{$\\\$$} \to X^i 1))))$
I leave the details to you, namely, verifying that $\Psi$ is of quadratic size in $n$, and digesting the formula. The idea is well-known, and appears, for example, here.
